# Console.GetKey equivalent in Vala

Tags: c#, console, vala

`stdin.getc()` waits for the user to hit enter before reading from the console. Is there any functionality in `vala` to grab keys as they are pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't provided in C, so there is no direct means in Vala. The best solution is to uses the Curses library and the binding for `Curses.getch()`.

Your alternative is to fiddle with the `tcgetattr`, which is in Vala's `posix` library, as per [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr).